# Piping data to from parent to children

Tags: arrays, c, concurrency, pipe, fork

For this project I'm working on I need to have the parent create a dynamic array with data from input count that tells you the number of data in the array. Then the parent must separate the data into approximately equal chunks and send it to N children. N is another thing typed by the user at input. I'm having an issue with my piping. Once my code separates the array into chunks and sends it to the children pipe I have a read issue in the child because I don't know how many integers in the chunk will be passed to the each children since it should be approximately equal chunks there will be some that aren't equal thats what the bonus variable measures. In order the get the size of each chunk I created  a chunkcount variable and I attempt to pass it to the child but I keep getting a weird issue.
below is example of my output:

** chunkcount is the correct count in the parent loop and child Chunkcount is the the chuckcount once passed to child. I notice that when I first do the read for chunkcount in the child it reads the data passed first and the chunkcount as allocated after that, so i'm not sure how to read the chunkcount data first so that the other read() in the child can use chunkcount to read that many number of integers.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 3

1 2 3 4 5 6 

I'm the parent --> 2179292
I'm child # 1 , with pid: 2179338
I'm child # 3 , with pid: 2179340
I'm child # 2 , with pid: 2179339
process 2179292 is sending data
chunkcount: 2

 child chunkcount: 1
chunkcount: 2
chunkcount: 2


 child chunkcount: 3
 child chunkcount: 5
2 child 1 recieved data
6 2 1909636606 32513 1 child 3 recieved data
4 2 1909636606 child 2 recieved data
Child PID 2179338 terminated with return status 0 
Child PID 2179339 terminated with return status 0 
Child PID 2179340 terminated with return status 0
```

```
    chunk_size = (count / N);
    int bonus = count - (chunk_size * N);
    int start;
    int end;

    // multi-dimensional array to initalize pipes for all children
    int fd[N][2];

int l = 0;
    
  
//  seperates file into chunks
//parent process
    for (start = 0, end = chunk_size; start < count; start = end, end = start + chunk_size)
    {
        int chunkcount = 0;
        if (bonus)
        {
            end++;
            bonus--;
        }
        // l is the child process to send the pipe to

        for (int o = start; o < end; o++)
        {  

           if (write(fd[l][WRITE], &ar[o], sizeof(int)) < 0)
            {
                perror("writing to pipe");
                exit(1);
            }
           chunkcount++;
        }
        printf("chunkcount: %d\n", chunkcount);
         if (write(fd[l][WRITE], &chunkcount, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            {
                perror("writing to pipe");
                exit(1);
            }
        l++;
    }
```

function called in child process that receives the data:

```
int child_work(int child_num, int fd[], int arr[])
{

    int ay[10];
    int chunkcount;
    
    if (close(fd[WRITE]) < 0)
    {
        perror("closing fd[WRITE]");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(read(fd[READ], &chunkcount, sizeof(int)) < 0){
        perror("reading chunknum");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n child chunkcount: %d\n", chunkcount);

    if(read(fd[READ], ay, chunkcount * sizeof(int)) < 0){
        perror("reading chunknum");
        exit(1);
    }

  
    for (int t = 0; t< chunkcount; t++){
    printf("%d ", ay[t]);
    }
    // loop to READ file descriptor for fk number of Data
   /*  for (int fk = 0; fk < count; fk++)
    {
        if (read(fd[READ], &arr[fk], sizeof(int)) < 0)
        {
            perror("reading to pipe");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%d ", arr[fk]);
    } */
    sleep(1);
    printf("child %d recieved data\n", child_num + 1);

    
}
```

Comment: Hint, the chunk count is `end - start`.

Comment: You need to write the chunk count before the chunk data because that is the order the child expects to read them.